# Check how many matching keys in the object

Tags: javascript

I have a following data in JavaScript:

```
{
  '0.Title': 'Title 1',
  '0.Detail': 'Detail 1',
  '1.Title': 'Title 2',
  '1.Detail': 'Detail 2',
  '2.Title': 'Title 1',
  '2.Detail': 'Detail 1'
}
```

I want to count how many times the `.Title` exist in the `key`. No matter its `0.Title` or `1.Title`.

I did like:

```
let count = 0;
while ('.Title' in fields) { // <--- fields is the above object
  count++;
}
console.log(count); // <--- gives 0
```

Comment: Do you want to count Title in key or value.

Comment: In the Key......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys` which will give an array of keys then use `map` to return an array of keys only but changing the case just to make sure that `title`
or `Title` or `TITLE` all considered same. Following that you can use filter to take out keys which have title keyword. This will return an array then you can use length

```js
let data = {
  '0.Title': 'Title 1',
  '0.Detail': 'Detail 1',
  '1.Title': 'Title 2',
  '1.Detail': 'Detail 2',
  '2.Title': 'Title 1',
  '2.Detail': 'Detail 1'
};

let k = Object.keys(data).map(e => e.toLowerCase()).filter(e => e.includes('title'));
console.log(k.length)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a reducer:

```js
const data = {
  '0.Title': 'Title 1',
  '0.Detail': 'Detail 1',
  '1.Title': 'Title 2',
  '1.Detail': 'Detail 2',
  '2.Title': 'Title 1',
  '2.Detail': 'Detail 1'
}


console.log(Object.keys(data).reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if(curr.indexOf(".Title") !== -1) acc += 1;
  return acc;
}, 0))
```